# Automatically set cuda variables in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to automatically set Variables to use cuda if a flag `use_gpu` is activated.

Usually I would do:

```
import torch
from torch import autograd
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()

foo = torch.randn(5)

if use_gpu:
    fooV = autograd.Variable(foo.cuda())
else:
    fooV = autograd.Variable(foo)
```

However, to do things faster when I have to initialise variables in different parts of the code I wanted to do something like this:

```
import torch
from torch import autograd
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()

class Variable(autograd.Variable):
    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        if use_gpu:
            data = data.cuda()
        super(Variable, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

foo = torch.randn(5)
fooV = Variable(foo)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working and `fooV` doesn't contain a cuda Tensor when the `use_gpu` is `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to use `type` method on CPU Tensor to convert it to GPU Tensor,

```
if use_cuda:
    dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor
else:
    dtype = torch.FloatTensor

x = torch.rand(2,2).type(dtype)
```

Also, you can find a discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-make-sure-that-pytorch-using-gpu-to-compute/4870/10).